# How to iterate over the headers in an Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In a http triggered Logic App I'd like to iterate over the incoming http headers and use only the *x-...* headers. These headers should be appended to a JSON message.

I know how to access the headers using `triggerOutputs()['headers']`, how to iterate over  collections and how to construct a JSON message using compose. But how to iterate over the headers?

Note: I don't know the x-... header names and I'd like to append any x-... header into the message, I don't want to update the Logic App if a new header is being added or one is removed.

I tried to create a ForEach that iterates over `triggerOutputs()['headers']`, but that's not a collection.

The header content:

```json
{
  "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "Accept-Encoding": "br,gzip,deflate",
  "Host": "prod-42.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443",
  "x-batch-uuid": "e74f68b9-d69e-4d50-bfe2-65bd6b38dd45",
  "x-event": "12361",
  "x-sequence": "1",
  "x-trigger-id": "sample-trigger-id",
  "x-trigger-time": "1672935303",
  "x-uuid": "66fa9513-ab42-4f31-90ff-b44582f7d72f",
  "Content-Length": "308",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

Current version with static x-header copy action

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "MessageBody": {
                "inputs": {
                    "data": "@triggerBody()",
                    "meta": "@outputs('X-Headers')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "X-Headers": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Send_message": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "ContentData": "@{base64(outputs('MessageBody'))}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('schedule-events'))}/messages"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "MessageBody": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "X-Headers": {
                "inputs": {
                    "x-batch-uuid": "@{triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-batch-uuid']}",
                    "x-event": "@{triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-event']}",
                    "x-sequence": "@{triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-sequence']}",
                    "x-trigger-id": "@{triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-trigger-id']}",
                    "x-trigger-time": "@{triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-trigger-time']}",
                    "x-uuid": "@{triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-uuid']}"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "person": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "href": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "personId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "servicebus": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus-1",
                    "connectionName": "servicebus-1",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/.../providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/servicebus"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the json that’s in the headers and we’ll produce and answer for you.

Comment: Yes, correct, you can't loop over it.  Composing off of it is also frought given properties may shift call on call depending on the origin or some other factor.  If there's a set of properties you know will always be there and be of a certain name, that's possible to achieve though.  Looping, though, not at present.  There is a connector that is adding this functionality, not sure if you're interested though?  There is a small ongoing charge.

Comment: Hmm.. okay. Thanks for the info. For now this hardcoded version is good enough. Eventually rewriting it to a Function App in the future.

Comment: A dirty solution is to use the split() expression which returns a string array:
split(string(outputs('my_object')),'",')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @skin, you cannot iterate for each loop over an object. Headers is an object, and we can iterate for each loop for array only.  As a workaround I have tried a below method. Kindly try if it helps in your case.

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. In for each loop, taken condition as shown below
   **if(startsWith(item(),'-x'),true,false)**
   [image]
3. Logic app ran successfully as shown below,
   [image]

Comment: nice workaround. Final solution will need a bit more plumbing as the header values will be json-formatted so the first and last item wil have a { or }. The value of each item will be like \"key\":\"value\" so that needs some kind of cleanup too.